# How to uninstall software by the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, uninstall, make

I am yet not a "Linux Guy" and I have the following problem

I installed some software from the source (compiling it), now I have to uninstall it.

What have I to do in the command line to uninstall it?

Comment: they generally will have uninstall script if not you will have to manually do it with rm file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the source files, you could be lucky and `make` provides an uninstall target:

```
make uninstall
```

If not, you'll have to manually inspect what `make` installed and remove these files. You can run:

```
make -n install
```

to see what is done during installation, and then use `rm` to remove the files that were installed.

---

In the future, instead of doing `make install`, you could use `checkinstall` instead. On Debian-based distributions, this would generate a `.deb` file which is installed like any other package, and which you can then later remove with Synaptic or `dpkg`.

Basically, instead of `sudo make install`, just call `sudo checkinstall`.